# login using single account across multiple different domain website

Tags: http, cookies, oauth-2.0, cross-domain, single-sign-on

**Requirement:**
I have two domain d1.com and d2.com, i want to use d1.com for account login/sigin only. if user loginto d1.com, he should automatically loginto d2.com. pretty simple!

**Example:**
I first want to give example.
like logging into google.com, automatically logs into youtube.com. I just want to limit this example to this 2 domain only.

**Steps:(my assumption)**
**1**. login to google.com
**2.** google store some cookies or oauth token at google.com domain level
**3.** open youtube.com
**4**. google try to check if user is already loggedin, but google cant access cookies or oauth2 token from google.com storage. so how does google know that this is same user, who logged into google.com
**5**. In order to get cookies or token info from google.com, youtube.com has to redirect user, to google.com but it does not do so. so how does google know that this is same user who logged into google.com
**6**. Is there any setting in client or server request headers that allow youtube.com to check cookies or token of google.com?

if anyone can help on elaborating the steps involved in implementing such requirement.

Answer (score 3):

It (YouTube) doesn't get Google's cookies. It sets it's own.

**The following is how you can implement something like that.**

S1.com - user site (YouTube)

S2.com - authenticating site (Google)

1. user request something from **S1**

   **S1** looks for user_token in browser cookies (so it can make API calls)

**[TOKEN NOT FOUND]:**

2. **S1** redirect to **S2** with public key (e.g. S2.com/get_auth/?public_key=xxxxx[&auth_url=xxxxx])

**[ON THE S2 OAUTH PAGE]:**

Note: the public_key, so **S2** will know which app is requesting an auth_key

Note: user will have to log in (if not logged in) and choose to grant your app permission

Note: auth_url is the URL to redirect to once user is logged in (optional as this could be set when you **register** your app at **S2**)

Note: you can also have cancel_url to handle user cancelling (failed logging in or granting access)

3. user logs in and grants access at **S2**
4. **S2** redirects back to **S1**(auth_url) with auth_key (e.g. S1.com/oauth/?auth_key=xxxxx)

**[ON THE S1 OAUTH PAGE]:**

5. **S1** auth_url checks for auth_key, if found, pings (send some data to) **S2** in exchange for a user_token (**in the back-end**)

   Note: the ping will involve sending data that identifies your app and the auth_key

   - e.g. { app_id: xxxxx, private_key: xxxxx, auth_key: xxxxx }
6. **S2** replies (to the backend call) with user_token if auth_key is valid

   Note: validating auth_key might involve, but not limited to, getting the public key associated with the auth_key (meaning when a valid public key request an auth_key, you must save both data for reference), then checking to make sure the public_key matches the private_key (and optionally app_id)
7. **S1** then sets it's **own** **user_token** cookie, and then use it to make API calls (to continue the user session)